# Jenkins: v1.605: Plugin Update check with "Check now" is not working

Tags: github, jenkins

I am very new to Jenkins and exploring Jenkins to use it for my project CI.

I installed Jenkins v1.605 today on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (trusty) system (brand new setup). I need github plugin to integrate with github source repository. Unfortunately my "Available" plugin list is empty. I made an attempt to update the available plugin list thru the "Check now" option of "Advanced" tab, however it of not much help. My browser is stuck at "Waiting for 10.10.1.2..."  status and "Update information obtained:" still shows N/A ago.

Below is the an excerpt from system info, which I thought might be useful to narrow down the issue

java.runtime.name   OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version    1.7.0_75-b13
java.specification.name Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor   Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version  1.7
java.vendor Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version    1.7.0_75

How do I get the available list of plugins onto my jenkins setup?

Anyway otherway to install github plugin directly as a stop gap messure?

Thanks in Advance
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should be:

```
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json
```

which is ip: 199.193.196.24 - so i guess your proxy is not working.

Comment: thanks, this gave me a clue. I found a working mirror and modified the URL and it working for me. For some reason jenkins get stuck in a bad mirror.. I found the same behavior with wget too..

Comment: This  URL is really great! I'm using `curl  -L http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json | sed '1d;$d' | curl -u username:password -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -d @- http://localhost:8080/updateCenter/byId/default/postBack` to upgrade the update center from CommandLine. Details can be found at [here](https://gist.github.com/rowan-m/1026918)